# Cocoa predefined resize mouse cursor?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nscursor

Is the resize mouse cursor used by **Preview** (e.g. when resizing shapes) a system cursor?

[image]

It's not available directly as a method in `NSCursor` but then it doesn't look like there's a private resource for the cursor in the Preview app's bundle either..

Are there more system cursors other than the methods defined by the `NSCursor` class..?

Answer (score 12):

I think you are particularly interested in these class methods (Preview.app dissasembly).

```
+[NSCursor resizeAngle45Cursor]; which calls +[NSCursor _windowResizeNorthEastSouthWestCursor];
+[NSCursor resizeAngle135Cursor]; which calls +[NSCursor _windowResizeNorthWestSouthEastCursor];
```

According to disassembly of AppKit these are private methods of NSCursor.

You can try it in your code e.g.

```
 (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
  [[self window] disableCursorRects];

  id cursor = [[NSCursor class] performSelector:@selector(_windowResizeNorthEastSouthWestCursor)];
  [cursor push];
}
```

There are more undocumented cursors such as

```
+[NSCursor _helpCursor];
+[NSCursor _zoomInCursor];
+[NSCursor _zoomOutCursor];
```

and many many more
[image]

Comment: Most of the above cursors are documented; search for them (without the leading underscore) at http://developer.apple.com. Most of them are at <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/>.

Comment: <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/>

Comment: You are right, but the question was about rotated resize cursors which I can't find in the documentation. Updated link to documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/AppKit_Versions_for_NSCursor_Bug_Fixes

Comment: Any idea where this is hidden in Swift? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297201/diagonal-resizing-mouse-pointer