# Diagonal resizing mouse pointer

Tags: swift, cursor, mouse

I am looking for the (hidden) mouse shapes which had been available with ObjC (see [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242353/cocoa-predefined-resize-mouse-cursor)). The Swift NSCursor offers none of those cursors you find for resizing standard windows?!

For now I'm just looking for the diagonal resizing mouse shapes. If the others were available it would be nice to know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor you describe is not supported by OS X. If you want a
cursor like that, you'll have to create an image of it yourself and
use the documentation already provided to create a cursor with that
image
WebKit contains images that look exactly the same as the cursors used by the system, in the following directory:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Resources/

[image: northEastSouthWestResizeCursor.png]
[image: northWestSouthEastResizeCursor.png]

Comment: LeftRight is horizontal. I'm looking for the **diagonal** cursor. Btw. it's Cursor, not Curser which means swearer.

Comment: @ThomasKilian The one you want is "resizenortheastsouthwest", also available in `/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors`

Comment: OMG. Typical Apple. Those cursors are used all over in OSX. I'll give that a try.

Comment: For the records: `cursorNWSE = NSCursor(image: NSImage(byReferencingFile: "/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Resources/northWestSouthEastResizeCursor.png")!, hotSpot: NSPoint(x: 8, y: 8))`

Comment: Funny enough: there's a NS cursor image, but none for EW :-/ Well, I'll take the resize-"standards" from NSCursor.